# How to dealing with the web element that have a changing "css selector" value in selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In selenium, is there a way I can get the css-selector value by providing the field name?

I am trying to write some selenium cases to fill-in some inputs in the following page.
[image]

But unfortunately, the elements on this page are neither id nor named. The only way I can reach these fields are by their css-selector values, something as if :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("...")
```

As at this moment I am looking at this web-page,

the css-selector value of the **Local Access Settings** area is:

```
#app > div.app > div > div > div.content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.section-title
```

and the css-selector value of the **http** text field is :

```
#app > div.app > div > div > div.content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.row > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.col-8.formik-custom-field > div > input[type=text]
```

But the painful part is, for both css-selector value, its "**div:nth-child(3)**" part is keep changing. It depends on the inputs on the previous page that leads to the current page.
It may be "*div:nth-child(4)*", "*div:nth-child(5)*", or even "*div:nth-child(6)*".

So I was thinking maybe I can find the css-selector value of  **Local Access Settings** string first, and then base on this to concatenate the css-selector string for the **http** text area.

So the question I have is how may I get the css-selector value if I was providing this "**Local Access Settings**" keyword in my selenium code ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the issue is changing CSS by child number like `div:nth-child(2)`  to  `div:nth-child(3)`
you can use some loops like this

```
import itertools 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

for i in itertools.count(start=1):
    try:
       self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#app > div.app > div > div > div.content > div:nth-child(' + str(i) + ')")
    except NoSuchElementException:
       pass
```

this will try the child number from 1 to unlimited number and you can add this to every child which is changing
use this `(' + str(i) + ')` on the changing element child number and if the issue is something else please acknowledge me

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i feel this would be my backup plan. Because there are other sections on that page, and there are chances that I don't such exception in the end, because other elements on that page matches this checking too.

Comment: you can use the loop on some specific ones and let other ones proceed normally and you can define loops as much as you want,  just change the string from i to a.b.c  I had a project like this and this was my best solution rather than that, please provide some example of your target URL

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have found a way to walk around to make the code working, as you suggested. But the code looks ugly to me. in general, should the the people who is creating the original web page be responsible to add either ID or name, which makes the rest work much easier ?

Comment: yes they are responsible for creating readable code but mostly they do that for a reason e.g: avoid scraping